# Capture the last group/word

Tags: regex, oracle

I want to capture the last word from the matched regexp. Here’s my query.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
'The;quick;brown;fox;jumps;over;the;lazy;dog','^([^;]*;){5}([^;]*)') REF
FROM
DUAL

Desired result: over
Actual Result: The;quick;brown;fox;jumps;over
```

I can do subregex but it will affect the performance if there are million of records…

Nested Regex

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(
'The;quick;brown;fox;jumps;over;the;lazy;dog',
'^([^;]*;){5}([^;]*)'),'[^;]*$') REF
FROM
DUAL
```

Comment: @JvdV Oracle does not support non-capturing `(?:)` groups. You would need to remove the `?:` and just get the 2nd capturing group.

Comment: Yeah, i'm just reading your answer. And i guess you covered it =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions if you are worried about performance (as they are slow), just use normal string functions:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(
         value,
         INSTR(value, ';', 1, 5) + 1,
         INSTR(value, ';', 1, 6) - INSTR(value, ';', 1, 5) - 1
       ) AS DATA
FROM   table_name;
```

If you did want to use a regular expression then just extract the value of a capturing group:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?);', 1, 6, NULL, 1) AS data
--                                    ^ Start from
--                                       ^ Occurrence
--                                                ^ Capturing group to extract
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'The;quick;brown;fox;jumps;over;the;lazy;dog' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | DATA |
> | --- |
> | over |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=83aa5cfaf65e29696acfe515eaadc55c)*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` then use its fourth parameter for the occurrence you are looking for:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         'The;quick;brown;fox;jumps;over;the;lazy;dog',
         '[^;]+',
         1,
         6) AS ref
FROM dual;
```

Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html#GUID-2903904D-455F-4839-A8B2-1731EF4BD099

Comment: Hi @Thorsten Kettner, yours also works. Thank you.